# First DFT line of the stft by scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, dft

I have manually implemented the STFT.
Comparison to the scipy.signal.stft revealed the same results as my implementation, except an additional DFT section at the beginning (t=0).
Can anyone write the script describing the first DFT, which I have probably missed?

my stft of the signal:
[image: my stft of the signal]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPIpw.png)

sci.signal.stft of the signal:
[image: sci.signal.stft of the signal][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WgTp.png)

the code:

```
def my_stft(samples, fs, wind_len_time=0.5, overlap_factor=0.5, 
                  zero_padding_factor=4):
    wind_len = int(fs * wind_len_time)
    overlap = wind_len * overlap_factor
    section_promotion = wind_len - overlap
    transform_len = wind_len * zero_padding_factor
    stft = []
    for index in np.arange(0, samples.size, section_promotion).astype(int):
        section = samples[index:index + wind_len]
        section_fft = np.abs(fft(section, n=transform_len))
        if not np.mod(section_fft.size, 2).astype(bool):
            section_fft = section_fft[:section_fft.size / 2]
        else:
            logger.debug('odd length fft') 
        stft.append(section_fft)
    time = np.arange(0, samples.size, section_promotion) / float(fs)
    freq = np.arange(section_fft.size) / float(section_fft.size) * fs / 2.0
    Freq, Time = np.meshgrid(time, freq)
    stft = np.array(stft).transpose()
    scaling = 2 / fs# onesided
    stft = stft * scaling
    return Time, Freq, stft
```

Comment: Can you show what your code is? This would greatly help to fix your issue.

Comment: Modified the question to include the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of the parameter boundary=None (in the scipy.signal.stft) will remove the first spectrum the t=0